# How to disable high bit charachter on IIS or Web.config on local web developer server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, extended-ascii

On production we have problem with generetad lookup urls, and special charachters within it.

System Administrators solved, as they say "Configuring headers and URLs blocking" with "Block high bit characters".

Now I'm trying to find a code solution, but I can't replicate the problem on my local developer machine.

I modified my Web.Config file with tags:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowHighBitCharacters="false">
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

but when I try to hit url like this on my local machine:

```
http://localhost/dir/myfile.aspx?par1=Ж&par2=Я&par3=Ы
```

I get no error...

What I fail in web.config? ...maybe I missed something in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

```
comment out the whole section below and run <location path="search">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering allowHighBitCharacters="true">
        </requestFiltering>

      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```